# Relationships in existing database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I inherit mysql database that do not have foreign keys . What i want to do is to document(diagram) of the relationships between the tables .  I have tried reserve engineer feature on MYSQL workbench but it does not show any relationship . 
Please i will appreciate any help.

Comment: How can we possibly help you without **any idea** what your database looks like. **We are not clairvoyant**

Comment: If there are no foreign key constraints defined in the database, then MySQL workbench can't reverse engineer them. Maybe the developer left some useful comments on the column definitions, e.g. `COMMENT 'fk ref someothertable.id'`. Barring that, maybe the developers used a naming convention, such as `id` for the primary key, and `someothertable_id` for foreign key columns. That may be of some help to you.

Comment: Failing any indications in the database definition, it would seem that your next best bet is to analyze how the database is used.  You could get an idea by logging queries and observing how tables are joined.  Alternatively, you could look at the source of the client program(s) for information.

Comment: In relational and ER modeling, FK constraints are just integrity constraints to enforce logical domains. Relationships are represented by the association of domains in a table.

Comment: - create schema-only backup of the DB
- restore the backup on your machine
- study the code and logical structure and add FKs (where possible)
- use the WB to make ERD

Comment: The `JOINs` will tell you how the tables are interrelated.  (Assuming they use the `JOIN...ON...` syntax).